# ElasticSearch Java API multiple filter is not working properly

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have indexed my Oracle table and I am trying to query using filters.

My Oracle table:

```
id      code        Attr_Label          locale          Value
1002    TE-7002     description         en_US           temperature valve
1002    TE-7002     description         en_ES           temperature valve
1002    TE-7002     Longdescription     en_US           High Temperture Valve
1002    TE-7002     Longdescription     en_ES           High Temperture Valve
1002    TE-7002     description         en_EU           High Temperture Valve tube
```

From this table, I query with `code : TE-7002` & `locale : en_US` and I'm expecting output as `description` Value and `Longdescription` Value (and it should be `en_US` locale).

I'm trying with multiple filter API and it's not working properly.

```
input query : `code : TE-7002` & `locale : en_US`
```

I'm expecting output like:

```
code : TE-7002
long_description : High Temperture Valve
description : temperature valve
```

Please find my Java API code:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US"))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "long_description"))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "description"));
```

For the above query, I'm getting empty (no results).

But if my query is like below:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "long_description"))
```

I'm getting results that do not satisfy `locale:en_US` condition, like:

```
code : TE-7002
long_description : HighTemperature Valve
```

Please find my mapping details:

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      },
    "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
     "attr_label":{
     "type":"text"
     },
     "locale":{
     "type":"text"
     },
     "value":{
     "type":"text"
     }

    }
  }
 }
}
```

**Update**

I'm able to filter on multiple value using `filters`. The modified working code is:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
         .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
         .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("attr_label", "long_description", "description"));
```

It's giving me the expected results.

Now, I have to add one more condition (filter) on it.

```
 QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
         .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
         .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("attr_label", "long_description", "description"))
         .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US")); // If I add this line it's giving `null` result.
```

I have tested it multiple times., only `locale` filter is not working. rest of the filters are working fine.

Comment: What is the result of your query?

Comment: @briarheart - i have updated my result in the question

Comment: @Karthikeyan Please Share the mapping.

Comment: @Richa - I have updated my mappings details.

Comment: @Karthikeyan i think it's 'locale' type issues

Comment: You are aware that *.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("attr_label", "long_description", "description"))* is not the same as calling `filter` 3 times right?

Comment: @Neil_TW - yes , might be problem with `locale` type. only `locale` filter is not working..

Answer (score 1):

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US"))
.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "long_description"))
.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "description"));
```

You must wrap terms queries you are using here into single boolQuery and use that as filter. It will be more or less like this:

```
QueryBuilder filters=QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
//add your filters here

    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
    .filter(fitlers);
```

Comment: Its giving empty (null) results.  ` QueryBuilder filters=QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US"))
      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "long_description"))
      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attr_label", "description"));
      QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
      .filter(filters); `

Comment: Only `locale` filter is not working., rest of all working fine.